# How to adapt a query so that it can perform all possible combinations (cross join) between elements of the same table?

Tags: postgresql, cross-join

Considering the following table:

```
group | type | element
------+------+--------
    1 |    1 | A
    1 |    1 | B
    1 |    2 | C
    1 |    2 | D
    1 |    3 | E
    1 |    3 | F
    2 |    4 | G
    2 |    4 | H
    2 |    5 | I
    2 |    5 | J
    2 |    5 | K
    3 |    4 | L
    3 |    4 | M
    3 |    4 | N
    3 |    5 | O
    3 |    5 | P
    3 |    6 | Q
    3 |    7 | R
    3 |    7 | S
    3 |    7 | T
```

I need to select all possible combinations between elements of the **element column**, but filtering through the **group column** and grouping by **column type**.

Using the following query I can do this query by filtering through the elements of **group 1** (this has types 1,2 and 3):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.type, T2.element, T3.type, T3.element
FROM (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 1 AND type = 1) AS T1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 1 AND type = 2) AS T2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 1 AND type = 3) AS T3;
```

Obtaining the following result:

```
group | type | element | type | element | type | element
------+------+---------+------+---------+------+--------
    1 |    1 | A       |    2 | C       |    3 | E
    1 |    1 | A       |    2 | C       |    3 | F
    1 |    1 | A       |    2 | D       |    3 | E
    1 |    1 | A       |    2 | D       |    3 | F
    1 |    1 | B       |    2 | C       |    3 | E
    1 |    1 | B       |    2 | C       |    3 | F
    1 |    1 | B       |    2 | D       |    3 | E
    1 |    1 | B       |    2 | D       |    3 | F
```

Already to filter by the elements of **group 2** I need to use another query reducing the amount of cross join because group 2 has fewer types (only types 4 and 5):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.type, T2.element
FROM (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 2 AND type = 4) AS T1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 2 AND type = 5) AS T2;
```

Obtaining the following result:

```
group | type | element | type | element
------+------+---------+------+--------
    2 |    4 | G       |    5 | I
    2 |    4 | G       |    5 | J
    2 |    4 | G       |    5 | K
    2 |    4 | H       |    5 | I
    2 |    4 | H       |    5 | J
    2 |    4 | H       |    5 | K
```

And finally to select the elements filtering by the **group 3**, I need to increase the amount of cross join because this group has 4 types (4,5,6 and 7):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.type, T2.element, T3.type, T3.element, T4.type, T4.element
FROM (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 3 AND type = 4) AS T1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 3 AND type = 5) AS T2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 3 AND type = 6) AS T3
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM test WHERE "group" = 3 AND type = 7) AS T4;
```

Obtaining the following result:

```
group | type | element | type | element | type | element | type | element
------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+------+--------
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | L       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | M       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | O       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | R
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | S
    3 |    4 | N       |    5 | P       |    6 | Q       |    7 | T
```

DOUBT!

How can I make a single query that can give me the results independent of the number of different (distinct) groups, types, and elements?

To better understand the relationships between group, type, and element type columns:

```
Group -> Type[element A, element B ...]

1 -> 1[A,B], 2[C,D], 3[E,F]
2 -> 4[G,H], 5[I,J,K]
3 -> 4[L,M,N], 5[O,P], 6[Q], 7[R,S,T]
```

Comment: I see no way to do this without dynamic SQL since the number of columns in the result set is dynamic.  So is this more than a cross join with dynamic pivot?

Comment: Let me see if I understand: a possible solution would be to use a sql with dynamic pivot?

Comment: that's a potential.  I'm not sure it would work but it would be the avenue I would pursue.